# Doing a Where clause that takes into account time zones

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm on SQL Server.
Let's say I have several records and a column of type datetimeoffset.

```
record #1 has a datetime with a +03:00 TZ
record #2 has a datetime with a +06:00 TZ
record #3 has a datetime with a -02:00 TZ
```

I want to show all records that their time has passed give the TZ of that specific record.
What would my WHERE clause look like?

Comment: I think the best thing would be create a new column using the case statement and get all the datetime to one particular Region Datetime. And then you can use the where clause. This would be simpler

Comment: You might want to take a peek here. [mcve]

Comment: @SeanLange There is no problem to reproduce.
It's a theoretical question.

Comment: So do you want a theoretical answer?

Comment: @SeanLange
Yes. Not looking for code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is too long for a comment, however, SQL Server ***already*** handles timezones gracefully:

```
USE Sandbox;
GO

CREATE TABLE TestTable (OffsetTime datetimeoffset(0));
GO
--Insert 5 times that are all the same time:
INSERT INTO TestTable
VALUES ('2019-10-15T17:00:00-02:00'),
       ('2019-10-15T18:00:00-01:00'),
       ('2019-10-15T19:00:00+00:00'),
       ('2019-10-15T20:00:00+01:00'),
       ('2019-10-15T21:00:00+02:00');
GO
--All rows
SELECT * 
FROM TestTable;

--All rows
SELECT *
FROM TestTable
WHERE OffsetTime = '2019-10-15T19:00:00+00:00';

--All rows
SELECT *
FROM TestTable
WHERE OffsetTime = '2019-10-15T21:00:00+02:00';
```

Provided you pass the timezone in your date and time as well, SQL Server will compare the values appropriately.

If, for some reason, you want to do "stuff" based on the time or date relative to the location, you should add a computed column that casts to a `datetime2` or `date` and `time` (depending on what you want):

```
ALTER TABLE TestTable ADD LocalTime AS CONVERT(datetime2(0),OffsetTime) PERSISTED;
GO

SELECT OffsetTime
FROM TestTable
WHERE LocalTime >= '2019-10-15T19:00:00';

GO
DROP TABLE TestTable;
```

Comment: As per your first example, consider inserting the same datetime with different timezones.
Then try to do a WHERE OffsetTime < getdate().

It will fail since it will be compared against the server's timezone

Comment: Why would I do that, @AlonSchachter ? That goes completely against my statement *"Provided you pass the timezone in your date and time as well, SQL Server will compare the values appropriately."* If I were to use a function like that I would use `SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()`.

Comment: yes perhaps you're right. comparing against sysdatetimeoffset() instead of getdate() might solve it